# How to globally change the ActionMap of Swing JTextFields?

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, jtextcomponent, uimanager

I want to change the ActionMap of Swing JTextFields in my entire Application by replacing a few actions by my custom implmentations. For an explanation why you can refer to the following post:

[How do I make the caret of a JTextComponent skip selected text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15554728/how-do-i-make-the-caret-of-a-jtextcomponent-skip-selected-text)

This works well if I do this:

```
ActionMap map = (ActionMap)UIManager.get("TextField.actionMap");
map.put(DefaultEditorKit.backwardAction, new MyCustomAction());
```

The only remaining problem now is that so far I have only gotten this to work, when I execute that code **after** the first instantiation of a JTextField. However, ideally I would like to integrate this code in a custom look and feel or some other central place that does not have to know about the application. Calling

```
UIManager.getDefaults()
```

first does not change anything. The map returned by *UIManager.get("TextField.actionMap")* is still null afterwards.

Right now I am Stuck with putting a dummy *new JTextField()* in some initialization method of my application and then manipulate the action map which is very ugly.

Comment: You can create your own `JTextField`(say `MyTextField`) by extending `JTextField` and change the `ActionMap` over there..And then use that overridden version of class throughout your program..

Comment: The only thing I can think of off the top my head is creating your own UI delegate, but, this would require to have one for each platform you intend to support

Comment: very good question, [there are implemented a few veriy interesting TextActions, have to waiting for real answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10075147/how-to-use-textaction)

Answer (score 2):

The shared parent actionMap is created at the moment when the *first* instance of a XXTextComponent gets its uidelegate. The method is in BasicTextUI:

```
/**
 * Fetch an action map to use.
 */
ActionMap getActionMap() {
    String mapName = getPropertyPrefix() + ".actionMap";
    ActionMap map = (ActionMap)UIManager.get(mapName);

    // JW: we are the first in this LAF
    if (map == null) {
        // JW: create map
        map = createActionMap();
        if (map != null) {
            // JW: store in LAF defaults
            UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put(mapName, map);
        }
    }
    ....
}
```

So if you want to add to that map, you have to do so after setting a LAF *and* after creating an instance.

There's no way around, even though it feels ugly.

Comment: +1, `There's no way around, even though it feels ugly.` That was the conclusion I came to yesterday as well. I was hoping you had more positive insight.